# Jenkins Pipeline - Jmeter Performance report

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the below Jenkins pipeline script to run the jmeter tests and make a report from a JTL file

```
node('master') {
    stage 'Run JMeter Test'
    def workspace = pwd()
    def jmeterTestFile = 'jenkins_test'
    echo "workspace = ${workspace}"
    echo "env.WORKSPACE = ${env.WORKSPACE}"
    bat "${workspace}\\jmeter\\bin\\jmeter.bat -n -t ${workspace}\\jmeter_scripts\\${jmeterTestFile}.jmx -l ${workspace}\\jmeter_scripts\\${jmeterTestFile}_results.jtl"
     step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'CP-Perf-Report.html,**/*.jtl, **/jmeter.log', fingerprint: true])
    //perfReport "jmeter_scripts\\${jmeterTestFile}_results.jtl"
    performanceReport parsers: [[$class: 'JMeterParser', glob: "jmeter_scripts\\${jmeterTestFile}_results.jtl"]], relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 1.2, relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 1.89, relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 1.8, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 1.5
}
```

Initially I tried creating report with `perfReport "jmeter_scripts\\${jmeterTestFile}_results.jtl"` command but it was failing with `FileNotFoundException` so I tried alternative way using `performanceReport parsers` but even then its failing again with `FileNotFoundException` but I can manually open the `c:\tools\jenkins\workspace\PerformanceTesting\jmeter_scripts\jenkins_test_results.jtl` file and see the test report. can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
workspace = c:\tools\jenkins\workspace\PerformanceTesting
[Pipeline] echo
env.WORKSPACE = c:\tools\jenkins\workspace\PerformanceTesting
[Pipeline] step
Archiving artifacts
Recording fingerprints
[Pipeline] step
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\tools\jenkins\workspace\PerformanceTesting\jmeter_scripts\jenkins_test_results.jtl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.ParserDetector.detect(ParserDetector.java:21)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.ParserFactory.getParser(ParserFactory.java:26)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.getParsers(PerformancePublisher.java:439)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.perform(PerformancePublisher.java:481)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:69)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use \\. I use \ in the command. You can check this link http://qainsights.com/integrate-apache-jmeter-jenkins/

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Yes I need to use \\ since its a groovy script in Jenkins Pipeline job

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any sign of running a JMeter test in the log so I would recommend amending your pipeline script as follows:

1. Convert `\\` slashes into `/` ones
2. Given you are running your test on Windows I believe you should be using variables in form of `%WORKSPACE%` rather than `${workspace}`

See following guides for references:

- [Building a software project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)
- [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial)